# Application pools settings

Tags: .net, web-services

Is it possible to set up programmatic what application pool to use  in my web service , and set it's parameters ?

I use vs2005 .

Thanks for help .

Comment: What version of IIS are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On IIS7 you could use Microsoft.Web.Administration assembly, look at ApplicationPool class

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.web.administration.applicationpool%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

NightWalker you can you powershell to programatically setup and manage sites.

```
Import-Module webadministration
New-WebAppPool -Name "Test 123 App Pool"
New-Website "Test WebSite" -ApplicationPool "Test 123 App Pool"
```

The following will setup and app pool and website, the website will use the app Pool.

Hope it helps